# ORA-01017 Invalid Username/Password whenever creating a new user or connection in Oracle SQL Developer 4.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Although I have some experience with SQL, my familiarity with it has waned, and I understand this is likely a very basic issue, but I'm having no luck finding any solutions. I'm trying to set up a new connection, but all of my attempts are being blocked. I have 3 connections- one entitled COMPANY, another "System", and a generic test one (they're all blank). The original and main connection was System, and that's where the other connections were created. No matter what I've tried at this point though, I get the same error message: "Status : Failure -Test failed: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied"

My attempts follow the pattern of entering this into the System worksheet:

```
CREATE USER user_name
IDENTIFIED BY password;

CREATE SCHEMA user_name
IDENTIFIED BY password;

GRANT all privileges to username;
```

And entering the desired password and such in the new connection window. No matter what, I get the same error, even when I change the password and username. What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: are u getting the error while connecting to oracle or while connecting to the user you created?

Comment: Did you copy/duplicate the new connection, and if so did you change the role back to 'default'?

Comment: I get the error while connecting to any user/new connection I try. I have not copied or duplicated the new connection, this applies to really any I try creating.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your Oracle SQL Developer has 3 connections defined and they are blank. Hence you are not able to connect to any of it.

In this case, there are only 2 ways I think of

1. Find someone who has the password for the connections.
2. Either you or your DBA should connect to Oracle as `SYSDBA` and reset the password

   ```
   alter user your_user identified by new_password;
   ```

   Example

   ```
   C:\Users\Utsav>sqlplus /nolog

   SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Sun Jun 11 14:29:52 2017

   Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

   SQL> connect as sysdba
   Enter user-name: sys
   Enter password:
   Connected.

   SQL> alter user devdb identified by *****;

   User altered.
   ```

Comment: No, the problem isn't that, I'm able to connect to those connections fine. My issue is that I'm trying to create a new connection with a new user, and my attempts within the System connection is blocked each time.